How to connect to FTP server between multiple subnets
I am using a ISP provided router (Huawei HG8145V5) which has inbuilt FTP server function.
The FTP server runs at 192.168.1.1:21 and I can access the FTP server within the network. However in order to increase the range of the internet coverage I have connected two more routers via Ethernet connection. These additional routers acts as a access point and use the ISP provided internet. Also the additional routers have been configured with diffrent sub-nets which are 192.168.8.1 and 192.168.9.1 respectively. The issue I am facing now is I am unable to connect to the FTP server via the other two local sub-nets and I would like suggestion to fix this issue.
Home network structure:

Router FTP server:

Device IP address:

Traceroute for 192.168.1.1:

Thanks in advance.

Why dont you just setup the additional routers to be in Access Point mode and not do any routing ? They will just acquire an ip address in the 192.168.1.0/24 range and you wont run into these issues.

You can do several things, but we need to have the model of the secondary routers

@user2046416 Sorry for being slow; On one hand, you say that there's a problem. On the other hand, you CAN ping that IP address. Yes?

If so, i'd suggest making sure the other routers don't have some default IP set to 192.168.1.1 / 254. If not, please clarify

You can either:

Add route in the secondary devices, to let them know that VLAN/segment 192.168.1.0/24 exists on the WAN port. That's assuming you're using the WAN port.
Connect the other routers using LAN ports ( not the ISP port, but one of the four that are similiar ), and disable their DHCP server. kinda like what Silbee suggested. That way, There'll only be one big network rather than different, small ones.

It really depends on the model of the secondary devices, and what features will they support.
*To clarify about LAN and WAN ports: WAN is being used to access other networks, while the LAN ports are for communication in the same network.
For example, your Huawei router have:

1 WAN port ( grey )
4 LAN ports ( yellow )



The secondary routers already know that 192.168.1.x exists on the WAN port, because they're in that network directly.

I was unable to implement the 1st method since my secondary router does not support it, however the 2nd method worked for me.

@grawity_u1686 yeah... the picture weren't there before haha

@user2046416 Glad I could help!

I actually thought I've already sent this message in this thread. Oh, well.
